# What does "statistical strength" mean in this context?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, recurrent-neural-networks, statistics

Consider the following excerpt from a paragraph taken from [chapter 10: Sequence Modeling: Recurrent and Recursive Nets](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html) of the textbook named [Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by *Ian Goodfellow et al* regarding the advantages of RNN over full traditional MLP.

> To go from multilayer networks to recurrent networks, we need to take
> advantage of one of the early ideas found in machine learning and
> statistical models of the 1980s: sharing parameters across diﬀerent
> parts of a model. Parameter sharing makes it possible to extend and
> apply the model to examples of diﬀerent forms(diﬀerent lengths, here)
> and generalize across them. If we had separate parameters for each
> value of the time index, we could not generalize to sequence lengths
> not seen during training, *nor share **statistical strength** across
> diﬀerent sequence lengths and across diﬀerent positions in time*. Such
> sharing is particularly important when a speciﬁc piece of information
> can occur at multiple positions within the sequence.

The authors used the phrase "statistical strength". Do they mean the strength of RNN in learning the embeddings of a word based on its context rather than its position in input, if it occurs in several inputs? Or does it mean that RNN uses [fewer parameters to generalize](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/27410/18758) in a better way compared to a traditional MLP? Or do they mean something else?